# Change formset default from collapsed to exanded?

Tags: forms

I'm working with the Support Ticketing System module in Drupal 7. My clients would like to be able to see at a glance who is subscribed to notifications on a ticket. The Subscribed field is collapsed by default, meaning the client has to click on the Subscribed link to expand the field to see the users subscribed.

How can I change this so that the field is expanded when the page loads, and save my clients a click?

EDIT: The node is variable--when creating a new support ticket, it will be /node/add/support-ticket. After the ticket has been created, it could be anything.

But the particular fieldset I want to target will always have the id "edit-subscribed".

Comment: It's probably a quick jquery or form alter snippet away. You should mention where the display is at (e.g. node page, view page, admin page, etc.) so someone knows what to target.

Comment: Edited to add more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) invocation can alter the default properties of the form. If you inspect the form array you'll see that the fieldset is stored in `$form['subscribe']['subscribed']`. By setting the [`#collapsible`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsible) element to `FALSE`, the or [`#collapsed`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsed) element to `FALSE` (if you want to retain collapsibility), the default behavior will be to keep the fieldset open.

For example:

```
function MYMODULE_form_support_ticket_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Replace #collapsible with #collapsed to retain collapsibility.
  $form['subscribe']['subscribed']['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Just noting, OP may prefer to set the [`#collapsed`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#collapsed) property to false, to preserve the collapsable fieldset functionality.

Comment: Good suggestion, updated.

Comment: Thanks very much--This works for the support ticket form, when you are editing a support ticket. But how can I make it work when you're just viewing a support ticket, where the form being displayed is comment-form rather than support-ticket-node-form? I see how to target the form ID, but don't see the in the support ticket module where the correct element is stored.

Comment: It's a different since it's not a form. Please that as a new question. We try to keep chatter to a minimum and focus on 1 question per post to make it more utilizable as a knowledge base.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks for the very helpful advice (on the hook, and on posting etiquette).

Comment: An update: The above function worked, but in the end it proved easier to use JQuery to alter the element class rather than a PHP function.