# Make support ticket subscriptions visible by default

Tags: forms

I have a Drupal 7 site using the [Support Ticketing System](https://www.drupal.org/project/support) module. When viewing a ticket, the client would like the Subscribed fieldset (id="edit-subscribed") visible by default. Currently it is collapsed, and you have to click on it to expand the field.

This problem is similar to a [previous post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/216504/change-formset-default-from-collapsed-to-exanded), where hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter() allowed me to expand the Subscribed field by default when the ticket was being edited.

But when viewing the ticket, the form in question is the comment-form, and I can't find the right array to target the edit-subscribed fieldset, if in fact the hook_form_alter is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It proved far easier to just add a line of JQuery to the page. `jQuery('#edit-subscribed').removeClass('collapsed');` added to the footer took care of it.